# Returning data from a IEnumerable

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, collections, lambda

Consider,

```
public class Obj
{
     public string PropertyName;
     public string Name;
     public int Id;
     public int Value;
}

List<Obj> lsObjdata = new List<Obj>();
var obj  = new Obj { Name = "xyz", PropertyName = "Volume", Id= 1, Value = 25};
lsObjdata.Add(obj);
obj  = new Obj { Name = "abc", PropertyName = "Volume", Id= 1, Value = 23};
lsObjdata.Add(obj);
obj = new Obj {Name = "abc", PropertyName = "Oil", Id =1, Value = 45};
lsObjdata.Add(obj);

IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, obj>> results = lsObjData.GroupBy( m => m.Id);
```

Now, my `results` will have 3 values for the same id.My Business requires me to give priority to the obj having `xyz` as the Name and omit the other if their properties match. But, If `xyz` doesn't have a property that `abc`has? fetch that property's value.Like the initialization of the third object given above.

```
obj = new {Name = "abc", PropertyName = "Oil", Id =1, Value = 45}
```

This property and value is not there with Name as `xyz`. This should get added to my final output. My Result should contain both the below objects in a list.

```
obj = new {Name = "abc", PropertyName = "Oil", Id =1, Value = 45}
obj  = new { Name = "xyz", PropertyName = "Volume", Id= 1, Value = 25};
```

**PS: I'm done with the solution already.** 
But, I was not able to use Linq/Lambda expressions and get the solution in a single line/stroke. 
Could anyone help me on that front? 
Thanks,
Sam

Comment: in which language would this compile?

Comment: You need to add `GroupBy` on two properties `ID` and `PropertyName` . That would give you a start.

Comment: @stefankmitph It's just the logic. Who told that it would compile anywhere mate?

Comment: @sam the tag c#-4.0 told me... no offence mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by two properties -  `Id, PropertyName` and then select the first object by ordering the grouped data like this:-

```
var results = lsobjdata.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.PropertyName })
                        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Name).FirstOrDefault());
```

Here is the [Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HHes3K) with some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not mention you that you want the first of every resultset. I am giving an alternate solution.

```
// Define other methods and classes here
public class Obj
{
    public string PropertyName;
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
    public int Value;
}

public class Key
{
    public string PropertyName;
    public int Id;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
    Key item = obj as Key;

        return item.Id == this.Id && item.PropertyName == this.PropertyName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + Id.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + PropertyName.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}

void static Main()
{
    List<Obj> lsObjdata = new List<Obj>();
    HashSet<Key>  keys = new HashSet<Key>();
    var obj  = new Obj { Name = "xyz", PropertyName = "Volume", Id= 1, Value = 25};
    lsObjdata.Add(obj);
    obj  = new Obj { Name = "abc", PropertyName = "Volume", Id= 1, Value = 23};
    lsObjdata.Add(obj);
    obj = new Obj {Name = "abc", PropertyName = "Oil", Id =1, Value = 45};
    lsObjdata.Add(obj);
    obj = new Obj {Name = "abc", PropertyName = "Gas", Id =1, Value = 45};
    lsObjdata.Add(obj);
    obj = new Obj {Name = "edf", PropertyName = "Gas", Id =1, Value = 45};
    lsObjdata.Add(obj);
    var results = lsObjdata.GroupBy(m => new Key { Id = m.Id, PropertyName = m.PropertyName })
                                .Select<IGrouping<Key,Obj>,IEnumerable<Obj>>(x =>
                                {
                                    if (x.Any(v => v.Name == "xyz") && !keys.Contains(x.Key))
                                    {
                                            return new Obj[]{x.First(v => v.Name == "xyz")};
                                    }
                                    else if (!keys.Contains(x.Key as Key))
                                    {
                                            return x.Select(v=>v);                                      
                                    }
                                    else
                                        return null;
                                })
                                .SelectMany(x=>x)
                                .Where(x=> x != null);

    foreach (var res in results)
    {

            Console.WriteLine(res.PropertyName + "  "+res.Name+"  "+res.Id+"  "+ res.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(results);
}
```

[image]